# In relation to Cal 1 Infinite Limits at Infinity

Tags: calculus

I am learning Infinite Limits at Infinity and I understand why you cannot take the sum of infinities as they are not a number.
However I do not understand why you can take their products.

Eg: $\lim_{x \to \infty} (x^2 - x) = \infty$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "Infinite is not a number" is a meaningless statement in mathematics. Among some numbers there are some called infinite. You can indeed sum some infinities.

Comment: @NDB Perhaps the original statement was "Infinity is not a *real* number" and the listener interpreted "real" in its daily sense.

Comment: To your question. Perhaps the definition of that limit is that for all $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that for all $x$ with $x>\delta$ you have $x^2-x>\epsilon$. That would be the definition of $\lim_{x\to+\infty}(x^2-x)=+\infty$. Ok, let's take $\delta=\max(1, \epsilon)$. If $x>\delta$, then $x^2-x>x^2>\delta^2>\delta\geq \epsilon$.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to make a distinction between *undefined* and *indeterminate*. When you have $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$$ in calculus, you typically say that the limit is undefined, because $\infty$ is not a real number. But there are still rules for working with infinite limits. In particular, if $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty \quad \text{and} \quad \lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = \infty,$$
then both of the following are true:

1. $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} (f(x) + g(x)) = \infty$
2. $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} (f(x) \cdot g(x)) = \infty$.

You can prove these using the formal ($\epsilon$-$\delta$) definition of a limit, but intuitively the idea is that both the sum and product of two functions that become arbitrarily large must also become arbitrarily large. Based on this, you might decide that you want to extend the definitions of $+$ and $\cdot$ to include the symbol $\infty$, and it would cause no problems to define $\infty + \infty = \infty$ and $\infty \cdot \infty = \infty$.

On the other hand, there is no way to give a good definition of $\infty - \infty$ or $\infty / \infty$ (or certain other expressions), and we call those expressions indeterminate. The reason we can't define them is that even if $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty \quad \text{and} \quad \lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = \infty,$$ we can't draw any conclusions about $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} (f(x) - g(x))$ or $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} (f(x) / g(x))$: for example, consider
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} (2x - x) \quad \text{vs.} \quad \lim_{x \to \infty} (x - x) \quad \text{vs.} \quad \lim_{x \to \infty} (x - 2x)$$
and
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^2}{x} \quad \text{vs.} \quad \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{x} \quad \text{vs.} \quad \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{x^2}.$$